# dúvida insert com while

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho esse while que me traz todos fornecedores que quero em um array, no qual posso editar seu nome, o meu problema é que quero fazer um insert desses valores em outra tabela, mas não tenho ideia de como faria isso, já que o "name" para fazer o post seria o mesmo para todos. Alguém teria alguma sugestão?

editado: com a ajuda do nosso amigo chegamos a este resultado porem não está pegando os valores e jogando nas variaveis #id... teria que ser $_POST['fornecedor#3'] por exemplo

```
if (array_key_exists("novoRecorrente", $_POST)){ 

$names = []; 
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { 
if (count(explode("#", $key)) == 2) { 
$names[explode("#", $key)[1]] = $key; 
} 
} 
foreach ($names as $key => $value) { 

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO contaspagar (contaspagar_fornecedor, contaspagar_valor, contaspagar_dv, contaspagar_status) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"); 
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $_POST['fornecedor'],$_POST['valor'],$_POST['dataV'],$_POST['status']);
$stmt->execute(); 
} 
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Acho que o ideal seria criar uma tabela para lista todos os fornecedores e uma outra pagina para edita-los

Comment: é que pensei pois essa lista pode ser dinâmica, aumentando com base no cadastro que vem do select

Comment: Sim, monta uma tabela através do PHP ou alguma lib tipo DataTables para criar uma lista com os fornecedores, cada fornecedor terá um link para uma pagina que carrega o fornecedor que foi selecionado

Comment: mas a ideia é editar todos de uma vez, pois vai ser um processo feito varias vezes, no exemplo coloquei só o nome do fornecedor mas vai puxar junto outras informações

Comment: ok, voce pode concatenar o id do objeto no name `name="nome_<?php echo $variavel['id'] ?>"` assim voce trata os `names` depois, pegando o id. É uma idéia

Comment: a ideia é boa, só uma dúvida.. como eu faria dai o insert no banco pegando esses dois parametros? ta meio confuso pra mim

Comment: você pode dar um `explode` no name, assim `explode('_', $variavel)`, assim você separa o id do name. Dessa maneira que você quer vai dar trabalho!

Comment: eu consegui colocar o -id no name... no arquivo que add no banco se eu adicionar os parametro com o - e o número está adicionando, não sei como seria o loop dai que traria o ID no lugar de setar o numero da id manualmente

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92879/discussion-between-leonardo-barros-and-murilo-albeest).